mod_deflate Logging on Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) does not work
Basics
I am running the Apache/2.4.62 on my Raspberry Pi 4B (ARM64/AArch64) with the Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm).

Some HW/OS info:
# neofetch

       _,met$$$$$gg.          root@rpi4
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ---------
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-28-arm64
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 1 day, 7 hours, 13 mins
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 476 (dpkg), 7 (snap)
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Terminal: /dev/pts/1
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         CPU: (4) @ 1.500GHz
 `$$b      "-.__              Memory: 199MiB / 7805MiB
  `Y$$
   `Y$$.
     `$$b.
       `Y$$b.
          `"Y$b._
              `"""


Preface
I recently enabled mod_deflate (Apache2 docs):
# a2enmod deflate

Considering dependency filter for deflate:
Module filter already enabled
Module deflate already enabled

After enabling it, I was curious about logging how much data is actually saved.
So, I went to edit the compression config file:
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf

With current contents:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>

        # Deflate compression level (maximum)
        DeflateCompressionLevel 9
        # Deflate memory usage level (maximum)
        DeflateMemLevel 9

        # Logging does not work, investigate
        DeflateFilterNote Input instream
        DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
        DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
        LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/deflate.log deflate

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

The compression itself should be working as expected as per online test:
https://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/
which told me:
https://programyburian.cz is Compressed
Uncompressed Page Size: 10.4 KB
Compressed Page Size: 3.1 KB
Savings: 70.7%


Actual Problem
Now my problem is Deflate logging, I tried many different configurations ending up with the one above. Also, as per comment, I tried placing its blocks in different order. No change.
# apache2ctl configtest 
Syntax OK

I even rebooted this machine, but still no luck, /var/www/logs/deflate.log is empty.
What can I do?

In this section of the Apache2 docs, it is stated:
DeflateFilterNote Input instream
DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
CustomLog "logs/deflate_log" deflate

which I implemented with one change, the CustomLog, see last line.
Maybe that is the culprit, I don't know really.
But I changed it because it did not work:
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.

Snippet from the log when failed to start:
# journalctl -xeu apache2.service

Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 systemd[1]: Starting apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 11533.
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 apachectl[26314]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02297: Cannot access directory '/etc/apache2/logs/' for log file 'logs/deflate_log' defined at /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf:24
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 apachectl[26314]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 apachectl[26310]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 apachectl[26310]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 18 01:34:19 rpi4 systemd[1]: Failed to start apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 11533 and the job result is failed.

So, I created the /etc/apache2/logs/ directory and restarted Apache, loaded my page with Ctrl+F5, Shift+F5, even tried different browser, the log remains empty...
Once I wake up in the morning I will try to add more information.

The problem with your current config seems to be the location of the log file, Apache expects it to be under ServerRoot or under APACHE_LOG_DIR, which Debian sets to /var/log/apache2.
So, just changing CustomLog from your current
CustomLog /var/www/logs/deflate.log deflate

to
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/deflate.log deflate

should fix the issue, and you will find the log at /var/log/apache2/deflate.log.
This is the modified tested version of your configuration:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>

        # Deflate compression level (maximum)
        DeflateCompressionLevel 9
        # Deflate memory usage level (maximum)
        DeflateMemLevel 9

        # Logging does not work, investigate
        DeflateFilterNote Input instream
        DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
        DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
        LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/deflate.log deflate

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>


Hello Eduardo, thank for your time! Sadly it did not help, do not ask me why, I rebooted the Pi even... Could you please share on what platform/hardware/system you tested it on? That could help a bit.

I have a Debian box, i686. I installed apache, put your configuration into /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf and it failed. After the modification I restarted apache and it worked and logged the correct information. Is that the file you modified? If you remove the CustomLog line, just that one, does it work? A stock apache will work with my config, but I don't know just how many other things you might have modified.

I'm beginning to hate this problem. Very well, I'll look into it once I have more free time, ok, I will hopefully provide some info. Thank you for your time!

It appears I have too many open issues to solve now... But since I do not want the bounty expire, I award it to you, hopefully I can get it to work too. Thank you, cheers, and merry christmas!

@VlastimilBurián thanks! Maybe you can start with the default apache configuration, and add your other customizations one by one. That might help. If you have more info on the error with this config, post it here and we'll try to help. Cheers!
